# React Native:How to trigger TextInput instance blur in a method?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I click a button on the navigator, the current screen's one TextInput's is focus.
I need to set the  TextInput's instance blur to trigger the `textChange` function to do something.

In my case, the cursor of TextInput is blinking all the time.

`refs.username.blur()` does not work.

[image]

My code :

```
class UploadRecordII extends Component{
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    headerRight: (<Button containerStyle={{marginRight: 12,}} onPress={ UploadRecordII.onSubmit}>
                  <Text style={{color: 'white',fontSize: 18,}}>next</Text>
                </Button>),
  });
.....


   static onSubmit() {
    let that = UploadRecordII.instance;
     debugger;
     that.refs.username.blur();
     debugger;
    that.props.commitCreateRecordUpdate(that.refs.username._lastNativeText,that.imageList)
    that.props.navigation.navigate('Record3');
  }



......  in render(){
....

<TextInput ref = 'username' placeholder='' editable = {true} maxLength = {500}
                  keyboardType='default' multiline={true}
                  style={styles.input} underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                           onBlur={  ()=> this.textChange()}
                  clearButtonMode='always' placeholderTextColor='#D6D0D8'></TextInput>



...
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with setting the `this.description` with `onChange` and then referencing `this.description` in your button pressed method? Also please copy your code instead of using  screenshots.

Comment: @BenjaminCommet I edit this question again. My code is change.

Answer (score 0):

refs don't work as strings anymore as expected. You need to define your ref e.g.

```
class UploadRecordII extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.usernameInput = null;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.usernameInput.blur();
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <TextInput ref={(input) =>  this.usernameInput = input} ... />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have modified my code with your advice.`this.usernameInput.blur();` doesn't work too.